# Making a request to back end and setting state with results creates infinite loop - react hooks useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

When a user goes to the edit page they will have the ID for the task they are editing. I need to make a request to the backend and set the state with the tasks text once.

What I have working:

```
let { id } = useParams();
const [task, setTask] = useState({ text: "", id: id });

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get(`/find/${id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      setTask({ ...task, text: res.data.text });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
```

If I remove the `// eslint-disable-next-line` I get an error telling me to add task and id as dependency, but when I do I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Is there a way I can make a request to the backend and set state once without having to hide eslint errors.

Comment: Not sure but try writing like this for setting the state : `setTask({ text: res.data.text, id: id })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the loop is infinite is because when you call `setTask` with the spread parameter, you are using the `task` from the `useState`.

To prevent this, call `setTask(task => ({ ...task, text: res.data.text }));` inside the `useEffect` so that it uses the current `task` inside the scope to calculate the new task state. Then you will be able to have `[task, id]` as the hook dependency.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up running into a similar issue and this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by passing the update method through props and adding the method as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
const updateEditText = props.updateEditText;

axios
  .get(`/find/${id}`)
  .then((res) => {
    updateEditText({ id: id, editText: res.data.text });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

}, [id, props.updateEditText]);